# Objeto no encontrado (R, principiante)

Tags: r, rstudio

Apenas aprenderé a usar lenguaje R pero tengo un error en las entradas
son ejemplos de internet:

```
my.name <- readline(prompt="Enter name: ")
my.age <- readline(prompt="Enter age: ")
# convert character into integer
my.age <- as.integer(my.age)
print(paste("Hi,", my.name, "next year you will be", my.age+1, "years old."))
```

Objeto 'my.name' no encontrado

```
nombre = readline(prompt = "tu nombre:")
edad = readline(prompt = "tu edad:")
print(paste("Mi nombre es", nombre, "y tengo", edad, años))
```

y obtengo

> nombre = readline(prompt = "tu nombre:")
>   tu nombre:edad = readline(prompt = "tu edad:")
>   print(paste("Mi nombre es", nombre, "y tengo", edad, años))
>   Error in paste("Mi nombre es", nombre, "y tengo", edad, años) : 
>     objeto 'años' no encontrado

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por el error y lo que comentas, entiendo que estás usando Rstudio y el problema se debe a la forma en que estás ejecutando el código. Seguramente algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes el código, lo seleccionas y haces click en el botón `"Run"` o presionas <kbd>ctrl  - enter</kbd>, el problema es que este es un tipo de ejecución que ofrece **Rstudio**, en que las líneas se van ejecutando de a una para ir capturando el comando y la salida para mostrar todo en el panel de consola y el problema radica en que esta forma podríamos decir que "no es compatible" con las instrucciones que esperan un "input" justamente de la consola.

En estos casos, debes ejecutar el código, no linea por linea sino en "lote", para esto tienes el botón `"source"` o <kbd>ctrl  - shift - S</kbd>.